# Sql Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am trying to store 40 txt documents in a database. First, I have created a table which holds the files ID's and names. Second, I created a table  `(WORDS)` which will store the content of all  40 txt files (word by word). I need to create a foreign key in table `(WORDS)` to reference each word to its original file where it is found.

Obviously this will be difficult If I do it manually since maybe a million words are there.

My first question: Is there any way I can do this approach automatically? using sql query ?

My second question: How would the sql server distinguish which word is in which file originally ?

Comment: Well, wouldn't whatever you're using to insert your text files into the database also insert the metadata (where found, etc.)?

Comment: Why do you need to store every word in its own row? Does a word by itself represent an "entity" to your system?

Comment: @derobert Inserting the words is not the problem, I am using BULK for that. Assigning each word to the foreign key of its file name is the problem.

Comment: @Adam Robinson I am making a search engine that should provide me with the word it finds and the file name it found it in.

Comment: @HumamShbib: Then use something like full text searching. **Don't** store each word as a row. That will be an enormous waste of space.

Comment: Forget using a database: This is a job for [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html), which is purpose built to do exactly what you are trying to do. Don't re-invent the wheel!

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server (and many other databases as well) supports full text search natively, which would be a much better solution in general than what you are proposing.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

That said, if you really are needing your approach, you can do something like the following:

```
CREATE table fileTable 
(
    ID int identity,
    nameOfFile nvarchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE(nameOfFile)
)
GO

CREATE table words
(
    ID int identity,
    word nvarchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    UNIQUE(word)
)
GO

CREATE table file_words
(
    fileId int,
    wordId int,
    FOREIGN KEY (fileId) REFERENCES fileTable(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (wordId) REFERENCES words(ID),
    UNIQUE(fileId,wordId)
)
GO

declare @fileContents nvarchar(max)
SET @fileContents = 'Hello world.  I am a silly word splitter.'
declare @fileName nvarchar(200)
SET @fileName = 'HelloSplitter.txt'


declare @whiteSpaceOrPunctuation table
(
    charVal nchar(1)
)

insert @whiteSpaceOrPunctuation
SELECT ' ' UNION ALL SELECT ',' UNION ALL SELECT ';' UNION ALL SELECT ':'
UNION ALL SELECT '-' UNION ALL SELECT '_'  UNION ALL SELECT '['  UNION ALL SELECT ']' 
UNION ALL SELECT '!' UNION ALL SELECT '.' UNION ALL SELECT '?' UNION ALL SELECT '%' 
UNION ALL SELECT '$' UNION ALL SELECT '#'
--etc...

declare @position int
declare @word nvarchar(max)
declare @fileLength int
declare @fileId int
declare @wordId int
SET @position = 1
SET @fileLength = LEN(@fileContents)
SET @word = ''
declare @currentChar nchar

INSERT fileTable (nameOfFile) VALUES (@fileName)

SELECT @fileId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()



while (@position <= @fileLength + 1)
BEGIN
    --print @position
    --print @fileLength

    SELECT @currentChar = SUBSTRING(@fileContents, @position, 1)

    --print @currentChar

    IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @whiteSpaceOrPunctuation WHERE charVal = @currentChar) OR @position = @fileLength + 1)
    BEGIN
        --print 'word: ' + @word
        IF(@word <> '')
        BEGIN
            --print @word

            SELECT @wordId = ID FROM words where word=@word

            IF (@wordId IS NULL)
            BEGIN
                INSERT words (word) VALUES (@word)
                SELECT @wordId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
            END

            IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM file_words WHERE wordId = @wordId AND fileId=@fileId))
            BEGIN
                INSERT file_words (fileId, wordId) VALUES (@fileId, @wordId)
            END
            SET @word = ''
            SET @wordId = null
        END
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        SELECT @word = @word + @currentChar
    END

    SELECT @position = @position + 1
END

--select * from fileTable
--select * from words
--select * from file_words

--drop table file_words
--drop table words
--drop table fileTable
```

Note this doesn't take into account upper vs lower case.  The behavior you get will probably depend on your [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260.aspx).

Also, it would be wise to wrap all of this in a transaction, which you could do either directly in this script or in whatever programming api you are using to make the db call.